# Cat with itchy skin

Tags: cats, skin-condition

About six months ago, I adopted two cats from a local shelter who are the light of my life. One of my cats, "Prof. Paws", seems to be prone to allergies and have a tendency to itchy skin. When I first got him, the vet diagnosed him with a flea allergy, and an infection where he was scratching. We treated that, and I give my cats flea treatments regularly even though they are indoor cats. He also had a slight problem with flatulence, but I switched him to a food for cats with allergies or sensitive stomachs, and that's gone now.

So Prof. Paws' health is good, but he still scratches a little bit more often than is normal. It's a mild problem, one that a human could probably solve with an occasional oatmeal bath (but a cat would not appreciate that!). **There are loads of nutritional supplements for cats that claim to improve skin condition; what ingredients should I look for to help with itching?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What food was he on vs what he's on now? If it's food related allergies you should try a food that has a different source of protein (ex. fish instead of chicken).

Dry itchy skin can also be a problem with the food itself (low quality food vs high quality) - Omega 3 + 6 fatty acids can help (do not buy human grade, veterinary is better).

There is also a product called [dermoscent](http://www.dermoscent.com/en/p102-essential-6-spot-on.html) that can help, it's a monthly topical and it's cheap!

If it's dry from winter where you live you can consider using a humidifier and place it where the cat spends most of his time.

Comment: He's now on Royal Canin Sensible (he was on Royal Canin Indoor, I think). I'll try the dermoscent, thanks!

Comment: Ah gotcha,  looking at ingredients they both have chicken and the sensible has animal fat (you'd have to call the company to find out what fats). So if it is food related you can try iams skin and coat - it's main source of protein is lamb. Chicken is a very common food allergen, though in general I don't see many cats with dietary allergies. If you try it out only feed him that food for around 10 weeks, if the itching persists then it's something else.

Comment: Dermoscent has been working well for us. I've come to the conclusion that he has sensitive skin rather than an allergy per se. When he gets stressed, his skin gets itchier. So in addition to the Dermoscent and lots of cuddles, I give him a "massage" once a day where I pet him slowly and firmly. This helps him relax; he usually falls asleep afterwards.